# Athena SQL query issue

Tags: mysql, amazon-athena

I'm trying to get the data from each value... It works fine with only one `AND url LIKE '%value%'`, but I'm missing something to be able to do multple values, please let me know

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM "access_logs"
WHERE year = '2018'
    AND month = '2'
    AND day = '22'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
group by url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need bracket around `OR`

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM "access_logs"
WHERE year = '2018'
    AND month = '2'
    AND day = '22'
    AND (url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%')
group by url
```

Comment: This worked, but do not like the results... How can I display each value with its own line. As it is, its displaying more than 6 lines.. way more lol

Comment: @Devon Try to include `url` in your `SELECT` to see what url you get for each row.  `SELECT url, COUNT(*) ...`

Comment: That returns the URL, I need the count per value for each line.. I usually  do one at a time, but now they want multple.. This is my old query `SELECT count(*)
FROM "access_logs"
WHERE year = '2018'
    AND month = '2'
    AND day = '22'
    AND url LIKE '%value%'` This returns just one line with counts.

Comment: I don't quite understand.  The query right now returns url and its count for each url.  What else do you need?  This is pretty much "each value with its own line".

Comment: Provide a current output and expected output so that we know what you want.

Comment: thx for helping.. old query with one value would give me (1 is the line number)
  `_col0
1 27268134` I need the output count for each value on a differtent line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165925/discussion-between-eric-and-devon).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should have all of the OR's in brackets like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "access_logs"
WHERE year = '2018'
AND month = '2'
AND day = '22'
AND (url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%'
    OR url LIKE '%value%')
GROUP BY url
```

Comment: This worked, but do not like the results... How can I display each value with its own line. As it is, its displaying more than 6 lines.. way more lol